# Is there a function to flatten a nested list of elements?

Tags: list, haskell

How can I flatten a nested list like this:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4] == flatten [[[1,2],[3]],[[4]]]
```

Comment: What you have is a list of lists of lists, so you're asking to flatten two levels.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that an arbitrarily nested list can be though of as a tree, which is easy to flatten (just recurse to the leaf nodes).

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Since nobody else has given this, it is possible to define a function which will flatten lists of an arbitrary depth by using MultiParamTypeClasses.  I haven't actually found it useful, but hopefully it could be considered an interesting hack.  I got the idea from Oleg's polyvariadic function implementation.

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses, OverlappingInstances, FlexibleInstances #-}

module Flatten where

class Flatten i o where
  flatten :: [i] -> [o]

instance Flatten a a where
  flatten = id

instance Flatten i o => Flatten [i] o where 
  flatten = concatMap flatten
```

Now if you load it and run in ghci:

```
*Flatten> let g = [1..5]
*Flatten> flatten g :: [Integer]
[1,2,3,4,5]
*Flatten> let h = [[1,2,3],[4,5]]
*Flatten> flatten h :: [Integer]
[1,2,3,4,5]
*Flatten> let i = [[[1,2],[3]],[],[[4,5],[6]]]
*Flatten> :t i
i :: [[[Integer]]]
*Flatten> flatten i :: [Integer]
[1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

Note that it's usually necessary to provide the result type annotation, because otherwise ghc can't figure out where to stop recursively applying the `flatten` class method.  If you use a function with a monomorphic type that's sufficient however.

```
*Flatten> :t sum
sum :: Num a => [a] -> a
*Flatten> sum $ flatten g

<interactive>:1:7:
    No instance for (Flatten Integer a0)
      arising from a use of `flatten'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Flatten Integer a0)
    In the second argument of `($)', namely `flatten g'
    In the expression: sum $ flatten g
    In an equation for `it': it = sum $ flatten g
*Flatten> let sumInt = sum :: [Integer] -> Integer
*Flatten> sumInt $ flatten g
15
*Flatten> sumInt $ flatten h
15
```

Comment: Very interesting. I thought you'd have to resort to Template Haskell to do this sort of thing.

Comment: @Dan: The `OverlappingInstances` extension allows something roughly approximating the ability to pattern match on type constructors, with the caveat that cases are chosen by specificity, not order of definition. It's a pretty "straightforward" bit of scary type-level metaprogramming hackery, and occasionally actually useful. Recursing through nested `(->)`s allows variadic functions, or with nested tuples stuff like heterogenous lists. It's all very enjoyable.

Comment: Yes, an interesting hack, but I don't recommend it for actual programming. -1 only because this is the highest scored answer and it shouldn't be.  (you can handle the -2 rep :-)

Comment: @luqui: as I said, I've never found this useful.  But it could be a chance for me to get the "Disciplined" badge.

Comment: Definitely an interesting hack! Thanks

Comment: However nice this may seem, trying something non-trivial, like `flatten [["item1", "item2"], ["item3"]] :: [String]` does not work. Also, the intent of `flatten [["item1", "item2"], ["item3"]]` is completely unclear.

Comment: @Rotsor: it makes perfect sense provided that you know `String` is a type synonym for `[Char]`.  Of course it's probably not what you want, but I'd say that's because `String` shouldn't be a type synonym in the first place.  It's a decision that causes trouble even in the standard Prelude type classes.  That said, I reiterate that I have not once found this construction useful, only interesting.

Comment: @luqui Why wouldn't you recommend using it? Because it will give cryptic error messages?

Comment: @CoolCodeBro, yes, and also that it interacts poorly with type inference (so if you use it in eg a `where` helper function with no signature you might get some confusing things happening), and also that it interacts poorly with polymorphism (as in the notes at the end of the post).  If you really want to understand its issues, just try to use it wherever you thought you needed it. You will learn. ;)

Comment: I think the `OverlappingInstances` or any other instance level pragma that it's depreciated in the favor of like `{-# OVERLAPPING #-}` is not required here.

Answer (score 117):

Yes, it’s `concat` from the Standard Prelude, [given by](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/standard-prelude.html#$vconcat)

```
concat :: [[a]] -> [a]
concat xss = foldr (++) [] xss
```

If you want to turn `[[[a]]]` into `[a]`, you must use it twice:

```
Prelude> (concat . concat) [[[1,2],[3]],[[4]]]
[1,2,3,4]
```

Answer (score 14):

As others have pointed out, `concat :: [[a]] -> [a]` is the function you are looking for, and it can't flatten nested lists of arbitrary depth. You need to call it multiple times to flatten it down to the desired level.

The operation does generalize to other monads, though. It is then known as `join`, and has the type `Monad m => m (m a) -> m a`.

```
Prelude Control.Monad> join [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
[1,2,3,4]    
Prelude Control.Monad> join (Just (Just 3))
Just 3
Prelude Control.Monad.Reader> join (+) 21
42
```

Comment: I don't get the third example... could someone explain it in little more detail?

Comment: @jhegedus the type of `(+)` is `a -> a -> a` which is the same as `a -> (a -> a)` one more step: `(a->) ( (a->) a )`, do you see the similarity between this and `[[a]]` which is the same as `[] ([] a)`?

Answer (score 10):

```
import Data.List
let flatten = intercalate []

flatten $ flatten [[[1,2],[3]],[[4]]]
[1,2,3,4]
```

Comment: Why would you use this over `concat`?

Answer (score 8):

As hammar pointed out, `join` is the "monadic" way to flatten a list. You can use the `do`-Notation as well to write easily flatten functions of several levels:

```
flatten xsss = do xss <- xsss
                  xs <- xss
                  x <- xs
                  return x
```

Comment: 5 years later, but you can simplify:  

```flatten = ((id =<<) =<<)```

Answer (score 4):

An arbitrarily nested list can be approximated by a `Data.Tree`, which can be flattened by the appropriately named function `flatten`.

I say approximated because `Data.Tree` allows a data item to be attached to every node, not just the leaves.  However, you could create a `Data.Tree (Maybe a)`, and attach `Nothing` to the body nodes, and flatten with `catMaybes . flatten`.

Answer (score 3):

You can remove one level of nesting using `concat`, and consequently you can apply n levels of nesting by applying `concat` n times.

It is not possible to write a function which removes an arbitrary level of nestings, as it is not possible to express the type of a function, which takes an arbitrarily nested list and returns a flat list, using Haskell's type system (using the list datatype that is - you can write your own datatype for arbitrarily nested lists and write a flatten function for that).