# haskell - nested empty lists

Tags: haskell, nested-lists

Hello Haskellers and Haskellettes,

when reading http://learnyouahaskell.com/ a friend of mine came up with a problem:

Is it possible in Haskell to write a recursive function that gives True if all sub-sub-_-sublists are empty. My first guess was - should be - but i have a big problem just writing the type annotation.

he tried something like

```
nullRec l = if null l
               then True
               else if [] `elem` l
                    then nullRec (head [l]) && nullRec (tail l)
                    else False
```

which is - not working - :-)

i came up with something like

- folding with concat - to get a a single long list
  (giving me problems implementing)
- or making an infinite treelike datatype - and making this from the list
  (haven't implemented yet)

but the latter sound a bit like overkill for this problem.
what is your ideas - on a sunny sunday like this ;-)

Thanks in advance

---

as a reaction to all the comments - this being bad style i'd like to add
this is just an **experiment**!
**DO not try this at home!** ;-)

Comment: Think about what the type of such a function should be (if you implement it on normal lists)!

Comment: i aleady thought about it - it should be kind of infinite [[…[a]…]] but that isn't possible to write down in haskell - that's why i came up with the second approach. But is there an easier way to do this.
Additionally my brain is a bit slow as i'm sick today.

Comment: Sick or not, you're on the right track! It's easy enough to write a family of functions `nullRec2 :: [[a]] -> Bool`, `nullRec3 :: [[[a]]] -> Bool` and so on (try a couple!), but you can't get them to fit a single type signature easily. You either need a tree type like `data Tree a = Branch [Tree a] | Node a` or maybe there's something possible with typeclasses (haven't thought much about this approach yet).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5994051 this might help

Comment: @FUZxxl's answer will work.  I consider the need to solve this problem a red flag -- if it were more than just an experiment, I would suggest rethinking the architecture.

Comment: i don't think i will ever occur this problem - it was just a thought experiment when stumbling over recursive functions - so no flags are necessary

Comment: To reinforce luqui's point, think about what the values of `nullRec [""]` and `nullRec [empty :: ByteString]` should be. You shall see that there is no good answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about a typeclass?

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances, OverlappingInstances #-}

class NullRec a where
  nullRec :: a -> Bool

instance NullRec a => NullRec [a] where
  nullRec [] = True
  nullRec ls = all nullRec ls

instance NullRec a where
  nullRec _  = False

main = print . nullRec $ ([[[[()]]]] :: [[[[()]]]])
```

Comment: More precisely, you are using not only a type class but also the GHC extension [OverlappingInstances](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.4/html/users_guide/type-class-extensions.html#instance-overlap).  Without this extension, even using a type class cannot achieve what is required in the question.  This strongly suggests that if anyone _has to_ implement this (other than as an experiment), the program is probably not designed in the right way.

Answer (score 4):

This is not possible using parametric polymorphism only, because of the following.

Consider these values:

```
x = [8] :: [Int]
y = [3.0] :: [Double]
z = [[]] :: [[Int]]
```

Obviously, you want your function to work with both `x` and `y`, thus its type must be `null1 :: [a] -> Bool`. *(Can someone help me make this argument look formal? How can I show that this is the unique most specific context-less type unifiable with `[Int] -> Bool` and `[Double] -> Bool`? Is there a name for that relation between types?)*

Now, if you have this type, then `null1 z` will be equal to `null1 x` because they differ only in values of the list elements, which are abstracted away from. *(Not even close to formal proof again :()*

What you want for `z` is `null2 :: [[a]] -> Bool`, which will differ in behaviour, and thus giving `null1` and `null2` the same name will require overloading. (see the FUZxxl's answer)

Comment: I find that argument fairly convincing.

Comment: I feel like `null1 . (:[]) :: a -> Bool` brings us closer to formal proof, but I still don't know how to make the last step (showing that `a -> Bool` is the same as `Bool`).

Comment: It's sort of a free theorem in reverse, but the largest lower bound of `Int` and `Double` (on the lattice of Haskell context-free types, with substition as the relationship) is `a`, as you can't substitute type variables in both of them (there aren't any!) and end up with the same type. Or am I getting my up & down directions mixed up?