# Couldn't match expected type in Haskell code that print nested list?

Tags: haskell

Here is my function

```
data Item a = One a | Many [Item a]
let flat (One x) = show x
let flat (Many xs) = show xs
```

Here is the output

```
Prelude> flat [[3]]

<interactive>:21:6:
Couldn't match expected type ‘Item t0’ with actual type ‘[[t1]]’
In the first argument of ‘flat’, namely ‘[[3]]’
In the expression: flat [[3]]
In an equation for ‘it’: it = flat [[3]]
```

It seems like flat doesn't recognize Item as its function signature so I tried redefine the function signature

```
flat :: Item a -> [a]

<interactive>:22:1:
    Couldn't match type ‘a1’ with ‘Char’
  ‘a1’ is a rigid type variable bound by
       an expression type signature: Item a1 -> [a1] at  <interactive>:22:1
Expected type: Item a1 -> [a1]
  Actual type: Item a1 -> String
In the expression: flat :: Item a -> [a]
In an equation for ‘it’: it = flat :: Item a -> [a]
```

But Haskell does not let you redefine function signature in ghci, is there a way around this?

Comment: I suspect you meant `One a | Many [a]`.

Comment: Don't you want `flat (Many ['3'])`? or `flat (Many [3])` without the type signature.

Comment: ah, that is unexpected, I guess what I am trying to do is to flatten out a nested list of arbitrary depth (I am debugging by printing stuff out right now), I thought I can define a new data structure to do that, but it seem like I actually have to define the type for each element? That seems to defeat the purpose. Is there a way to pattern match Many vs One

Comment: Check this question out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9507358/haskell-flatten-a-list-of-lists

Comment: @Kevin But `show` can already handle arbitrarily-deeply nested lists... why introduce another data structure at all? Perhaps you can show a bit more context, since this seems like you have a legitimate problem and are asking about some trouble you are having with a particular solution to that problem, when a better solution exists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`flat [[3]]` yields a type error.  `[[3]]` has type `Num a => [[a]]`, not `Show a => Item a` that you can pass into `flat`.

`flat (Many [3])` will return `"[3]"`.

Comment: Is there a way to automatically detect `[3]` to be Many type without explicitly defining it?

Comment: @Kevin you _could_ write a custom Read implementation for it and do `flat . read` (with the appropriate type specified), but other than that, no; you'd have to define it as `Many [One 3]` to get it to go through `flat`.

Answer (score 1):

Answering a follow-up question you asked in the comments of @jtobin's answer: yes there is a way to automatically dectect that `[3]` needs to be wrapped into a Maybe constructor. However you'll probably need to add type annotations (cf. `example` to help Haskell figure out what to do=.

We start with a bunch of language extensions.

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses  #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FunctionalDependencies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances      #-}
```

Then comes your definition of `Item`.

```
module Item where

data Item a = One a | Many [Item a]
```

We introduce a class of things which may be reified to an `Item a` and declare two instances: the `Many` one and the base case. You can see that we now have overlapping instances (e.g. for Itemable [Int] [Int]) so you're playing with fire here.

```
class Itemable b a where
  item :: b -> Item a

instance Itemable b a => Itemable [b] a where
  item = Many . fmap item
instance Itemable a a where
  item = One
```

You can finally define `flat` as a function that turns a `b` into an `Item a` first and then flattens it:

```
flat :: Itemable b a => b -> [a]
flat = go . item where
  go (One a)   = [a]
  go (Many as) = concatMap go as
```

Which works as the following example typechecking and evaluating to `[2,43,7,8,1]` shows:

```
example :: [Int]
example = flat [[[[[[2::Int],[43]],[[7],[8]],[[1]]]]]]
```

However, as soon as you try to use the overlapping instances it'll blow in your face. E.g.:

```
example' :: [[Int]]
example' = flat [[[[[[2::Int],[43]],[[7],[8]],[[1]]]]]]
```